# Is it possible to specify formatting options for to_yaml in ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml

The code

```
require 'yaml'
puts YAML.load("
is_something:
  values: ['yes', 'no']
").to_yaml
```

produces

```
--- 
is_something: 
  values: 
  - "yes"
  - "no"
```

While this is a correct yaml, it just looks ugly when you have a hash of arrays.  Is there a way for me to get `to_yaml` to produce the inline array version of the yaml?

*An options hash can be passed to  [`to_yaml`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/classes/Array.html#M010476) but how do you use it?*

Edit 0:  Thanks Pozsár Balázs.  But, as of ruby 1.8.7 (2009-04-08 patchlevel 160), the options hash does not work as advertised. :(

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts [[ 'Crispin', 'Glover' ]].to_yaml( :Indent => 4, :UseHeader => true, :UseVersion => true )
--- 
- - Crispin
  - Glover
=> nil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ugly hack seems to do the trick...

```
class Array
  def to_yaml_style
    :inline
  end
end
```

Browsing through ruby's source, I can't find any options I could pass to achieve the same.  Default options are described in the [lib/yaml/constants.rb](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk/lib/yaml/constants.rb).

Comment: To print only small arrays inline:
class Array; def to_yaml_style(); self.length < 5 ? :inline : super; end end

Answer (score 11):

About the hash options: see http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/examples.htm

Ex. 24: Using `to_yaml` with an options Hash

```
puts [[ 'Crispin', 'Glover' ]].to_yaml( :Indent => 4, :UseHeader => true, :UseVersion => true )
# prints:
#   --- %YAML:1.0
#   -
#       - Crispin
#       - Glover
```

Ex. 25: Available symbols for an options Hash

> `Indent`: The default indentation to use when emitting (defaults to `2`)
>   `Separator`: The default separator to use between documents (defaults to `'---'`)
>   `SortKeys`: Sort Hash keys when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `UseHeader`: Display the YAML header when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `UseVersion`: Display the YAML version when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `AnchorFormat`: A formatting string for anchor IDs when emitting (defaults to '`id%03d`')
>   `ExplicitTypes`: Use explicit types when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `BestWidth`: The character width to use when folding text (defaults to `80`)
>   `UseFold`: Force folding of text when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `UseBlock`: Force all text to be literal when emitting? (defaults to `false`)
>   `Encoding`: Unicode format to encode with (defaults to `:Utf8`; requires Iconv)

Comment: Doesn't work.  From the source, I am not even sure if the opts hash is being passed down to syck.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Ruby 1.9 `psych` is used as a default YAML engine. It supports some attributes: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Handler/DumperOptions.html

So for me it works:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> puts [{'a'=> 'b', 'c'=> 'd'}, {'e'=> 'f', 'g'=>'h'}].to_yaml(:indentation => 4)
---
-   a: b
    c: d
-   e: f
    g: h
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another hack to specify the output style, but this one allows to customize it per specific object, instead of globally (e.g. for all arrays).

https://gist.github.com/jirutka/31b1a61162e41d5064fc

Simple example:

```
class Movie
  attr_accessor :genres, :actors

  # method called by psych to render YAML
  def encode_with(coder)
    # render array inline (flow style)
    coder['genres'] = StyledYAML.inline(genres) if genres
    # render in default style (block)
    coder['actors'] = actors if actors
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Ruby use the Psych module for YAML parsing. There aren't many options that you can pass but you can change indention and line width. Check the latest [Psych documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-dump) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use Psych directly.

Indentation has no effect:
`my_yaml.to_yaml(:indentation => 2)`

Indentation works:
`Psych.dump(my_yaml, :indentation => 8)`