# How to get the formatting options for the to_yaml method working on ruby 1.9.1?

Tags: ruby, yaml, to-yaml

According to the YAML documentation it's possible to pass a [hash of options](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/the_options_hash.htm) to the `.to_yaml` method.

Currently when I pass the options as suggested by the documentation it's not working, the hash is being ignored.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> user = { "1" => { "name" => "john", "age" => 44 } }
user.to_yaml
=> "--- \n\"1\": \n  name: john\n  age: 44\n"
```

Now, passing some options:

```
irb(main):014:0> user.to_yaml( :Indent => 4, :UseHeader => true, :UseVersion => true )
=> "--- \n\"1\": \n  name: john\n  age: 44\n"
irb(main):015:0> user.to_yaml( :Separator => "\n" )
=> "--- \n\"1\": \n  name: john\n  age: 44\n"
irb(main):016:0> user.to_yaml( :separator => "\n" )
=> "--- \n\"1\": \n  name: john\n  age: 44\n"
irb(main):017:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.1"
```

As you can see, passing the options don't work. Only the defaults:

```
YAML::DEFAULTS
=> {:Indent=>2, :UseHeader=>false, :UseVersion=>false, :Version=>"1.0", :SortKeys=>false, :AnchorFormat=>"id%03d", :ExplicitTypes=>false, :WidthType=>"absolute", :BestWidth=>80, :UseBlock=>false, :UseFold=>false, :Encoding=>:None}
```

Is this a known bug? or It's currently working for anyone using Ruby 1.9.1 ?

Comment: I get the same behavior as you are seeing.  It looks as if this has been asked before without resolution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054730/is-it-possible-to-specify-formatting-options-for-toyaml-in-ruby

Comment: Yes, in that case they were using 1.8.7, I was just wondering if it works for 1.9.1, it seems to be a problem without a concise answer.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this one.  I long ago gave up and wrote my own "sort the yaml" function (for 1.8.7).

Comment: Is 1.9.1 using the same presumably abandoned _why YAML writer as 1.8.x? I've had nothing but trouble with it when trying to send options and customize it.

Comment: @tadman, From looking at the source, I'd say "yes" for 1.8.7, 1.9.0 and 1.9.1.

Comment: I had so much trouble with it trying to serialize HAML HTML that I gave up and switched to JSON. Sadly it's quite buggy around the edges.

Answer (score 2):

I have dug relatively deep into the C source for this in the not so distant past. I'm posting just to validate what's already been said in the comments.

Basically, can't do it. The Syck options get lost somewhere in the process, before ever hitting the YAML writer.

The best you can have is `to_yaml_style`. Sometimes.

This is the same for 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: Ok, well I ended writing a small module to get it formatted, not as optimal as it should be using the `to_yaml` method ... but at least it works. Thanks.