# Can I change the number of spaces while writing yaml using YAML::dump?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am writing a yaml file as follows:

```
File.open('output.yaml', 'w') do |f|
  YAML::dump(yaml, f)
end
```

The content within the written file uses 2 spaces for indentation. How can I change the number of spaces? Say I want 4 spaces instead of 2, can this be done? I couldn't find any solution to do this, other than processing the whole file after writing the yaml.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass [options to Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/1-2-stable/test/psych/test_psych.rb) (psych is the default yamler):

```
File.open('output.yaml', 'w') do |f|
  YAML::dump(yaml, f, indentation: 4)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the version ruby 1.9.2 I am using has syck as the defauly yamler and it does not support the indentation option. Unfortunately, I am not at liberty to upgrade the version.

Comment: @Amar I thing there is something like `:Indent => 4` for syck

Comment: @Amar check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054730/is-it-possible-to-specify-formatting-options-for-to-yaml-in-ruby